# Pylint on files within Directory and subdirectory?

Tags: python, pylint

I have a python project contains python files within the parent directory and even in its children directory. I want to analyze all the python files within the directory. However I do not want to specify the name of folders. Is there a way which will help me out. The hierarchy may vary but the script should still work.
Thank You.

Comment: Could you give a clearer example of the structure of your project and the failed attempts you've made to lint it?

Comment: Look into `os.walk`

Comment: Actually I want to use this script in jenkins. Where the pylint should analyze all files in my job. I am storing the project directories in a local directory.

Comment: You could write a python-based build job that uses `os.walk` and jenkins build parameters for folder paths to scan for ".py" files, do the pylint command (outputing results to job output dir), and optionally return an error from the job. Then just put that job in the build chain.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a shell script which will go over the files and run lint:

```
for file in /Project/*; do
   if [ -d $file ]; then
    for subfile in $file/*; do
        if [[ $subfile == *.py ]]; then
            pylint $subfile
        fi
    done
    fi
    if [[ $file == *.py ]]; then
        pylint $file
    fi
done
```

Comment: Perhaps a pure python solution so you are not limited by underlying platform.

Comment: It works fine when I use it in my terminal. But when I put this script in my jenkins as a  post build script it does not work.

Comment: Just to clarify, have you given the full path of the folder in the script??

Comment: No I have given the full path because before that I am creating a virtual environment.

Comment: /tmp/hudson7662013801206915644.sh: 21: /tmp/hudson7662013801206915644.sh: [[: not found this is the error I get

Comment: I think you are executing the script using sh. Which is a different shell.
You should run this script using bash.

Answer (score 2):

If your project is a proper [python package](http://blog.habnab.it/blog/2013/07/21/python-packages-and-you/) (i.e. a folder with an `__init__.py` basically), you can simply run `pylint packagename`.